# How to run a react project when react is added as peer dependency

Tags: reactjs, jsx, peer-dependencies

I'm trying to run a repo from Github locally. The folder structure for react is somewhat different what what I usually see in a react project(I'm new to react). the folder structure is like

-index.js 
-css folder 
-jsx folder - components 
-jsx folder - index.html 
-jsx folder - index.js

Also react is added as a peer dependency. I'm not sure how to run this repository. Any help is much appreciated

React in package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you able to show us the `scripts` currently in the `package.json` e.g. "start"?

Comment: Start is not there. Actually I was able to contact the developer. Its library file so he asked me to npm install library and make changes in a new react project. It's strange I have never worked on a repo like this before

Comment: Hmmm... that's interesting. What library is that again?

Comment: Library and version - "sriracha-ui": "^1.8.9".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was library files. So I had to create a new project using create-react-app and install the library in my new project and then make changes.